# If $A$ is nowhere dense, then $Int(\overline{A})=\emptyset.$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, baire-category

A set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is nowhere dense if for any interval $I,$ there exists a subinterval $J\subseteq I$ such that $J \subseteq A^c.$

$x\in A$ is an interior point if there exists an open interval $I$ of $x$ such that $I\subseteq A.$

We denote $Int(A)$ as the set of all interior points of $A.$

> **Statement**: If $A$ is nowhere dense, then 
>   $$Int(\overline{A})=\emptyset.$$

My attempt:
Suppose that $$Int(\overline{A})\neq\emptyset.$$
Let $x\in Int(\overline{A}).$
By definition of interior, there exists an open interval $I$ of $x$ such that $I\subseteq \overline{A}.$

By definition of nowhere dense of $A,$ there exists a subinterval $J\subseteq I$ such that $J\subseteq A^c.$
Then we have 
$$J\subseteq \overline{A}\cap A^c.$$
I do not know how to proceed from here. 
I think there is a contradiction, but I fail to see it. 
Any hint will be appreciated.

EDITED: $x\in \overline{A}$ if for any open interval $I$ containing $x,$ we have $I \cap A \neq \emptyset.$

Comment: Hint. Pick a point $y\in J.$ Then $y\in\overline A$ and $J$ is a neighborhood of $y$ which is disjoint from $A.$ I can't go any further bucause I don't know how you define $\overline A$, but I think you should be close to a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I). If $J$ is an open set then for any $A$ we have $J\cap \overline A=\phi \iff J\subset A^c.$

(II). If $Int (\overline A)\ne \phi$  there exists a non-empty open interval $I\subset \overline A.$ Then no  non-empty open interval $J\subset I$ can be a subset of $A^c.$ Otherwise $J\cap \overline A=\phi$, implying $$\phi=J\cap \overline A =(J\cap I)\cap \overline A=J\cap (I\cap \overline A)=J\cap I=J\ne \phi$$ which is absurd.

So if $Int (\overline A)\ne A$ then $A$ is not nowhere-dense.

(III). If $Int(\overline A)=\phi$ and $I$ is any non-empty open set then $I\setminus \overline A$ is a non-empty open set so there exists a non-empty open interval $J\subset (I\setminus \overline A).$ Since $J$ is open and disjoint from $\overline A$ we have $J\subset A^c.$

So if $Int(\overline A)=\phi$ then $A$ is nowhere-dense.